# Civil servant = government employee?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Does a civil servant always represent an employee who works for a government (government employee)?

Comment: *Soldiers and military officers* who work and fight for, and receive salary from a governement are not called *civil servants*.

Comment: Some people who wok for organisations like the World bank, the IMF etc describe themselves as *International Civil Servants*. In  their case they are not directly employed by any government, but such as the UN.

Comment: The U.S. pays 22% of the U.N. budget and they are 22% civil servants of the U.S. Government.

Comment: @Rathony Given the long years when the US didn't pay anything, and the fact that there are still outstanding arrears of $1.3billion - that is a small price to pay!

Comment: @WS2 They have 19 billion debt. They should be proud of themselves. BTW, Most of it is owed to China!!!

Comment: @Rathony I was talking merely about arrears of UN fees.

Comment: @Rathony - Your opening comment seems to address the inverse of the question. The question asks, "Are all civil servants government employees?" not, "Are all government employees civil servants?"

Comment: @J.R. The right answer is "a civil cervant doesn't always represent employees working for a government." If you agree with this, please look at my comment again.

Comment: @Ranthony - Your comment does not provide an example to your "right answer." An example would be a civil servant who does **not** work for the government, rather than someone who works for the government yet is not a civil servant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Free Dictionary defines a *[civil servant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/civil+servant)* to be

> a member of the civil service

and the *[civil service](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/civil+service)* to be

> 1. Those branches of public service that are not legislative, judicial, or military and in which employment is usually based on
>      competitive examination.
> 2. The entire body of persons employed by the civil branches of a government.

so all civil servants are government employees, but not all government employees are civil servants.

The situation in Britain is complicated by the existence of *[quangos](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quango)*:-

> An organization or agency that is financed by a government but that
>   acts independently of it.

whose employees look like and act like civil servants but may or may not be formally part of the civil service.

Comment: It's very useful.

Comment: I refuse to believe that *quangos* are unique to Britain. I had this argument with an American. I don't see how any modern western country can avoid there being quangos.

Comment: @WS2, quite so. But I don't know what they are called in other countries (although the entry in the dictionary doesn't say it's _Chiefly Brit._ or anything of that sort).